# Python interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have a set of data that looks like:

```
Table-1 
    X1    | Y1
    ------+--------
    0.1   | 0.52147
    0.02  | 0.8879 
    0.08  | 0.901
    0.11  | 1.55 
    0.15  | 1.82
    0.152 | 1.95

Table-2
    X2   | Y2
    -----+------
    0.2  | 0.11
    0.21 | 0.112
    0.34 | 0.120  
    0.33 | 1.121
```

I have to interpolate the `Y2` value from Table-2 for the `X1` values from Table-1, i.e., I need to find the values of `Y2` for the following values of `X`:

```
    X1     |  Y2
    -------+-------
    0.1    |
    0.02   |
    0.08   |
    0.11   |
    0.15   |
    0.152  |
```

Note: Both Table-1 & 2 have unequal intervals. The number of (X, Y) entries will differ, for e.g., here we have 6 (X1, Y1) entries in Table-1 and only 4 (X2, Y2) in Table-2.

Which interpolation algorithm should I use in Numpy, and how do I proceed?

Answer (score 32):

[`numpy.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) seems to be the function you want: pass your `X1` as the first argument x, your `X2` as the second argument xp, your `Y2` as the third argument fp, and you'll get the Y values corresponding to the `X1` coordinates.

```
Y2_at_X1 = np.interp(X1, X2, Y2)
```

I'm assuming you want to completely ignore the existing `Y1` values. This is what the above snippet does. Otherwise you'll have to clarify your question to explain what role you might have for `Y1`!

If you want more than linear interpolation, I suggest you look at [`scipy.interpolate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) and its [tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) rather than trying to stretch numpy beyond its simplicity ;-).